# Approach to checking if something is in the correct order (which is not the usual order)

Tags: python, list

Say we have a defined order of items in a list which is not the usual output if you cast `sorted()` on it, e.g. `definedlist = ["P, R, T, L"]`. How would I check if the values in a list of lists I'm iterating through are adjacent or not (be in the same order of the defined list)?

E.g. `["P,R,T"]` has to be in that order if I sort that particular list to be a valid input, but `["T, L, P"]` would be invalid. If a better description is required please let me know.

Comment: Would it help if you convert the lists to strings and check if string A is in string B? I.e. `definedstring = "".join(definedlist)` and `string1 = "".join(["P", "R", "T"])` and check `if string1 in definedstring`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do custom sorting quite easily, even though depending on how many elements you have, it could be a bit costly.

An example:

```
sort_lookup = {
        "P": 0,
        "R": 1,
        "T": 2,
        "L": 3,
    }

s = ["T", "L", "P", "R"]
if (s == sorted(s, key=lambda x: sort_lookup[x])):
    print("SORTED")
else:
    print("NOT SORTED)
```

Comment: what exactly does lambda do? but this is very applicable to my problem! will use it.

Comment: I just want to add that Im actually doing this for a card game... but A is the lowest value (=0). I've assigned each of them values. It is possible for them to be unsorted, for instance AC, 3D, 2H (clubs, diamonds, hearts) can be a valid input but i just need to check whether the actual sorted version of that is equivalent to the particular order (eg: A, 2, 3) Additionally, the values all have to be adjacent to one another.